# Uploading Excel file using VBA to SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, upload

Im struggling to resolve an upload problem direct from excel to sharepoint. I have the right permissions and can upload no problem when hardcoding the URL. Issue I have is all the SharePoint URL's are by Project Number and Description for example:

```
  https://teamzzz.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects/NL001%20%20TEST/10.%20Dispatch
```

The project is called NL001 in this case. Another example of a URL could be:

```
  https://teamzzz.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects/ZNP001%20%20ANOTHERTEST/10.%20Dispatch
```

Basically at the point of attempting to upload using my Add in I know the first part of the PATH:

```
  https://teamzzz.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects/
```

The project id I can find from a cell reference:

```
  NL001
```

The last part of the URL will always be the same as in:

```
 10.%20Dispatch
```

My problem is the description after NL001 i.e. "%20%20TEST" (see below):

```
 https://teamzzz.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects/NL001%20%20TEST/10.%20Dispatch
```

Is there anyway I can use some form of wildcard in the URL for example:

```
 https://teamcde.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects/NL001*/10.%20Dispatch
```

OR

```
 https://teamcde.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects/NL001%/10.%20Dispatch
```

The above 2 example dont work but was demonstrating the example I require. Here is my code thus far:

```
 Public Sub CommandButton39_Click()                 

 ProjectFileName = Range("B2").Value

 SharePointBasePath = "https://teamcde.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects/"

 SharePointEndPath = "10.%20Dispatch/"

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SharePointBasePath & ThisFile & ".xlsm" & SharePointEndPath

 End Sub
```

Is is possible to utilise a wildcard as the description is not known at time of upload.

Thankyou

Comment: The wildcard makes no sense, so is not implemented.  Suppose you had a NL001A and a NL001B folder.  You want the save command to divine which of the multiple folders is best to save in?

Comment: The Project ID is fixed length buddy and is referenced in cell B1. In SP there is a constraint on the property for the ID and Description. I just want to build the URL around the Project ID. The Project ID is always unique also